# Conditional Probability involving condition on two RVs

Tags: conditional-probability, density-function, conditional-expectation

Suppose X,Y~exp(2) and are independent. Let W=X+Y.

How do I set up integrals to calculate the following:

f(W|X>Y)

E(W|X>Y)

Thanks!

Comment: The quantities are the same as unconditional $f()$ and $E[]$ because $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed. Statement $X > Y$ does not tell us anything new. One variable will always be higher than the other.

Comment: Why isn’t it telling anything new? Aren’t we omitting all the cases where Y>X?

Comment: One number will always be larger than the other. Who cares whether it's $X$ or $Y$? Think about it........... Symmetry.